# Render Dictionary Enum keys as named values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an Enum looking something like this:

`public Enum MyEnum {EnumA = 0, EnumB = 10, EnumC = 20}`

I also have a Dictionary model that I wish to use in my Razor view in which I would like to assign the keys of the Dictionary to a javascript array like this:

`var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Keys.ToArray()))`

This results in `myArray = [0,10,20]` which is pretty close to what I want. I would like the "text" value of the enum to be added instead of the numerical values, like this: `myArray = ["EnumA","EnumB","EnumC"]`

When displaying a single enum field `@Html.DisplayFor` can be used to convert the numerical value to the enum "text" value.

Is there a way to have my keys converted in the same way without having to loop through them and add them to the array manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var values = Model.Keys.ToArray().Select(val => val.ToString());
var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(values));
```

If the keys are still of type `MyEnum` then they should automatically be expressed as the names of the enum values.

If that doesn't work, you could also try this:

```
var values = Model.Keys.ToArray().Select(val => ((MyEnum)val).ToString());
var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(values));
```

This assumes that if your keys aren't still of type `MyEnum`, they are at least integers.

Be aware that if the values in the keys don't correspond to defined `MyEnum` values (say, if you defined values 1-4 and the key was 17) you'll still get the key value as a numeric string.

Comment: Nice! Never thought of using select like this. Razor complains about `values` not existing in the context though. I put everything into one line and it works perfectly but the two line version is more readable. Any idea of why it does not recognize that values is defined on the line above?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, and I'm not currently working in VS (and don't have it on this machine) so I can't experiment and try to figure it out.  Sorry!

Comment: Incidentally, I realized after posting that you could probably take out the `.ToArray()` in the first line. While I can't verify this, I believe `Model.Keys` will already be a type that LINQ can use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Enum.Parse`;

```
var array = new List<int> {0, 10, 20};
var arrayEnum = array.Select(x => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), x.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Also a great solution!

Comment: This is a good solution, but you can also cast integers directly to an enum, as in `(MyEnum) x`.  You don't have to generate strings and then parse the strings.  Probably the cast would be faster than the parse.